# VBA Adding Single Quotes Around Text in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created the following to comma separate a list of numbers within a ms-word document.  However, I also want to wrap each number with single qoutation marks - which I am struggling to get right.  I have managed to wrap the first number however I cant execute it for the others.  Each number is 12 digits long.  Can someone assist?

```
Sub Macro1()

    With Selection
        .Find.Text = "^p"
        .Find.Replacement.Text = ","

        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .TypeText Text:="'"
        .MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=12
        .TypeText Text:="'"

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative and quicker solution is to use wildcards for another find-replace. Complete code will look as follows:

```
Sub Macro1()

    With Selection
        '1st step- replacement paragraph marks into commas
        .Find.Text = "^p"
        .Find.Replacement.Text = ","
        .Find.MatchWildcards = False
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        '2nd step- adding single quotation marks
        .Find.Text = "([0-9]{12})"
        .Find.MatchWildcards = True
        .Find.Replacement.Text = "'\1'"
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think a single replace with .MatchWildCards = True, Find.Text = "([0-9]{12})^13" and Replacement.Text = "'\1'," Will also do it, as long as the list is paragraph-delimited.

Comment: @bibadia, you are absolutely right. I wanted to show evolution in relation to OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the transformation outside of the With block, I think.

I am not a Word VBA expert, so this is an approach that uses common string functions, rather than replicating keyboard input. So, there are likely different approaches to accomplish the same task :) I suspect this is the "correct" way to do it, since it's generally advisable not to mimic "input" but rather to work directly with the objects.

**Revised so that you do not need to physically "Select" the text**

Note: this uses *all* text in the document, so you may need to modify.

```
Sub Test()
Dim doc As Document
Dim arr As Variant
Dim txtRange As Range
Dim i As Long

Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set txtRange = doc.Range(0, doc.Characters.Count)

'First, replace the paragraph breaks with commas
With txtRange.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = ","
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With


arr = Split(Left(txtRange.Text, Len(txtRange.Text) - 1), ",")

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    arr(i) = "'" & arr(i) & "'"
Next

txtRange.Text = Join(arr, ",")

End Sub
```

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

I have confirmed absolutely that this is working. Please double-check that you have implemented the code correctly.  Here is an example of some text which meets your description:

[image]

I select that text, and run the macro, stepping through it using F8.  At the end of the `With` block, observe that the paragraph breaks have been replaced with commas:

[image]

After the `For...Next` loop has exited, I confirm using the Locals window, that the new array now contains numbers enclosed in single quotes:

[image]

The next line prints out those items from the array, and replaces the `Selection.Text`, confirmed:

[image]

Comment: This only manages to input the commas and not the single qoutes.

Comment: Please see the screenshots above, which confirm this replaces the commas **and** inserts the single-quotes.  If that is not happening for you, either A) you did not implement the code correctly, or B) there is something funky about your document which you did not adequately describe, so I can not replicate. If you think this is the case, please add a screenshot(s) or example data that I can test.

Comment: sorry I didnt realise you had to phyiscally select the data first.  it works fine.  thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries! I made a modification so that you don't have to physically select the text, instead it will use *all* text in the document.  Modify as needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I have re-worked my original code, and this runs really quickly over large data sets. I've now added in brackets at the start and end of the code too.

Sub TestN()

```
Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = False
'Replace the paragraph breaks with commas and single quotes
With ActiveDocument.Range(0, ActiveDocument.Range.End - 1).Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "','"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = True
'Cap body of data with single quotes and brackets
ActiveDocument.Content.Text = "('" & ActiveDocument.Range(0, ActiveDocument.Range.End - 1).Text & "')"
```

End Sub